# What is this cement coating?

Tags: patio, cement, porch, sealer, sealant

I have this coating on my front porch which is starting to disintegrate. I think the porch slab is probably still good, so I want to just replace the coating but I can't figure out what it is. I'm almost positive that it was added to the porch to add traction; especially when wet. Can someone help me identify this?  I could also use some advice on how to replace it... I'm looking for a good solution to clean up how this looks, not necessarily a perfect solution.

This coating is very hard like the cement, and became damaged from salt, also similar to cement.

[image: the porch]

Comment: At first I was thinking it was a skim coat but it looks rougher than the stuff I use. it may be a [resurface](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Quikrete-40-lb-Concrete-Resurfacer-113141/20228988) type of cement product. from the way it is chipping i believe it is a cement based product. A high pressure, pressure washer will help knock any loose stuff out. After a good pressure washing a resurface product should cover well.

Comment: @EdBeal What product do you recommend?  I'm clueless when it comes to cement.

Comment: I have used the quikrete resurface product with a powdered color added on several small jobs. it is easy to put down. the face of the step may take a bit more work to trowel it on.

Answer (score 1):

It's too gritty be a Textured Paint. And, the color & material seems to be full depth, so it's not a colored Resurfacer topped with sand or even a Stucco. But, you can go with any of those to match the surface look...after a lot of trial & error on a board.

But, I'm more inclined to think it's the stuff below applied at almost twice the thickness, allowed to setup & then water hose flooded & broomed down to expose the grains & aggregates.

[image: Quikrete Sand Topping Mix]

Answer (score 0):

It could be [magnesite](http://www.contractflooringjournal.co.uk/archive/helpmay03_2013.html). Not easy to repair